# Error in differentiation/integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, implicit-differentiation

(**Edited** to directly present the problem only, for any future readers. The original question can be read in the revision history.)

Is the following correct?

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\int y\,dx\right) = x$$

If not what is the correct solution?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dy}\int y(x)\,dx\ne x$$Rather, it is equal to $y(x)/y'(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a bit more precise notation and define $f(x)=x^3+x^2$.  Then, with $y=f(x)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
z(x)&=\frac{d}{dy}\int f(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\left . \left(\frac{d}{dy}\int y\,\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}\,dy\right)\right|_{y=f(x)}\\\\
&=\left.   \left(y\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right)\right|_{y=f(x)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow the process from the first step to the second step. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Substitute $x=f^{-1}(y)$.  Then, $f(x) = y$ and $dx = \frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}\,dy$